# Possibility to construct std::tuple's elements later with an allocator?

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator, stdtuple

As far as I understood it, one reason to use C++'s allocators for my own container would be that I can seperate allocation and construction.

Now, I wonder if this is possible for std::tuples in the following way: Each time I construct an std::tuple, the space is reserved, but the objects are not constructed (yet). Instead, I can use the allocator in order to construct the i-th argument just when I want to.

Pseudo-Code:

```
struct my_struct {
    const bool b; // note that we can use const
    my_struct(int x) : b(x==42) {}
};

int main()
{
    std::tuple<int, my_struct> t;
    // the tuple knows an allocator named my_allocator here
    // this allocator will force the stack to reserve space for t,
    // but the contained objects are not constructed yet.

    my_allocator.construct(std::get<0>(t), 42);
    // this line just constructed the first object, which was an int
    my_allocator.construct(std::get<1>(t), std::get<0>(t));
    // this line just constructed the 2nd object
    // (with help of the 1st one

    return 0;
}
```

One possible problem is that allocators are usually bound to a type, so I'd need one allocator per type. Another question is whether the memory for the std::tuple must be allocated on the heap, or if stack might work. Both is ok for me.

Still, is it possible somehow? Or if not, could this be done with an allocator I write my own?

Comment: Try [`std::get_temporary_buffer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/get_temporary_buffer) along with the uninitialized storage algorithms.

Comment: Here's some [proof of concept code](http://ideone.com/o23e79) that demonstrates how I might do it, but I have absolutely no idea if that's valid C++.

Comment: @KerrekSB: the precondition of any standard library function called with an object or a reference/pointer to such an object is that the object exists (unless explicitly stated otherwise). Clearly, in uninitialized memory there is no object.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I was hoping for some kind of "`&*` does not evaluate the operand" magic... I was also considering member pointers, but didn't know how to get one of those for tuples (probably "base pointers" would be the right thing in that case).

Comment: @KerrekSB Not sure, maybe this is what I wanted. What does the `new` code line mean? Which version of [this doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/new/operator%20new/) does it correspond to? I guess version 3?

Answer (score 1):

Allocators won't help you with initializing objects: the role of an allocator is to provide *raw*, i.e., uninitialized memory. The allocator could be used with a `std::tuple<...>` to customize how, e.g., memory for a `std::string` or a `std::vector<...>` is allocated.

If you want to delay construction of objects you'll need to use something like an "optional" object which would indicate with flag that it isn't constructed, yet. The implementation strategy for a corresponding class would be a wrapper around a suitable `union`.

Comment: Thanks, but could you please go more into detail? What does it have to do with a union (or maybe a variant)? Note that I do not want to initialize only one element of the tuple, but maybe multiple, and they should live at the same time.

Comment: Also, for the raw memory argument: Does it help you if you can allocate the `std::tuple`'s space on the heap?

Comment: @Johannes: a `union` is the only way which works to embed a not-yet-constructed object portably into another object (an array of the same size, for example, may fail to work due to initialization issues). If multiple elements go together you might want to put them into a nested `std::tuple<...>` (and possibly use a custom `get<...>()` function which considers them not nested).

Comment: @Johannes: a dead object is a dead object. It doesn't matter where an object is not constructed: until it is constructed you can't use it [portably].

Comment: @Johannes: There is an [example at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Unrestricted_unions) of using `union`s to construct different objects in a location but it should be straight forward how the same can be done to use an optionally constructed object instead.

Comment: You mean by "portably" that many of the functioality of a std::tuple is unsafe until the tuple object is fully constructed? Ok, true, but if I only access the tuple elements of which I know they are constructed? Then why should it not work?

Comment: @Johannes: what I mean with "portably" is that it is guaranteed by the standard to have defined behavior. When traveling in undefined behavior things may appear to work or systems may even provide guarantees but these won't apply everywhere. The relevant section in the standard is 3.8 [basic.life] especially paragraph 5. You might enjoy [this page on undefined behavior](http://dspace.dial.pipex.com/town/green/gfd34/art/bloopers.html).